# Calling friend function from class method

Tags: c++

Why I cannot call friend function from a class method? It should have a class scope:

```
class A {
public:
    friend void foo() {}
    void f() { foo(); }
};
```

Compiler says:

> 'foo' was not declared in this scope

Comment: to use that you first need to declare/define `foo()` (above the class)

Comment: This isn't what friends are for. You don't normally call friend functions from inside the class; you invoke friends outside the class and *use* the class inside of them.